XPath to select EventLog record where source contains string
I am writing an XPath query string to select records from the Windows Event Log where the Event source contains a particular string. I have a version which performs an exact match where the Path element of the query is
Path='Application'>*[System[Provider[@Name='MyApp']

This works fine, but I want to find all events where the source contains 'MyApp'. I have read various articles and I think it should be
Path='Application'>*[System[Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp']

but this fails with an 'Invalid Query' error.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Update:
I edited my query in line with the fix below and my full query string is now:
var Query = @"<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='Application'>
                        <Select Path='Application'>*[System[Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp')] and (Level=2 or Level=3)]]</Select>
                        </Query></QueryList>";

var EventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, Query);

but this still fails. If I change the query to be
var Query = @"<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='Application'>
                                <Select Path='Application'>*[System[Provider[@Name='MyApp'] and (Level=2 or Level=3)]]</Select>
                                </Query></QueryList>";

it all works.
Does the EventLogQuery support 'contains'. This article How to select for content contains substring in Windows Event Viewer using XPath 1.0? suggests it does not.


Your posted XPath is missing a closing ) for contains() and closing predicate ] for several levels:
*[System[Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp']

should be
*[System[Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp')]]]


More conventionally, for a top-level Event element this would be written
/Event[System/Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp')]]


Take into account the namespaces typically involved.  Given the following sample Windows Event Log XML,
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" 
              Guid="{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}" />
  </System>
</Event>

by declaring a namespace prefix,
e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"

and using it in your XPath,
/e:Event[e:System/e:Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp')]]

See How does XPath deal with XML namespaces? for how to declare and use (or defeat if necessary) namespaces in XPath.

The above assumes that you're using a full, compliant XPath processor/library.  Apparently Windows Event Log is not (thanks to the link provided by @JamesCockayne, +1):

Windows Event Log supports a subset of XPath 1.0. For details on the limitations, see XPath 1.0 limitations.

In general, it's better to use a fully compliant XPath processor/library.



I think the issue is that the contains function is missing a closing parentheses. I also think we are missing some closing square braces. I'm not sure how your first example works.
Try *[System[Provider[contains(@Name, 'MyApp')]]]
This guide seems to have many good examples that you should be able to modify to meet your needs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events

Thanks for posting the Windows Event Log documentation link.  (+1)  I've updated my answer to note per the docs that the built-in querying there is only a subset of XPath (ugh).

@kjhughes Apologies I didn't see your answer at first! I wrote it out as soon as the question was posted, but couldn't post it for 30 minutes after answering another, so just left the tab open. It seems rather inadequate now!

On the contrary: Your answer is correct, and that doc link leading to the revelation that their XPath implementation is incomplete is very helpful.
